# Spark Streaming - KafkaWordCount Cannot Run on a Spark Standalone Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I need your help and advice for running Apache Spark KafkaWordCount example on a standalone spark cluster :

I can run Spark example, KafkaWordCount, in local mode through

```
spark-submit .... --master local[4] ....
```

and I can get the message from Kafka Server, which is in another node (Virtual Machine) and get the results printed on terminal console.

**However**, when submitting the application to spark standalone cluster (via

```
spark-submit .... --master spark://master:7077 ....
```

), I found Exceptions in each worker node's directories of **$SPARK_HOME/work/../../stderr** directory.
And each word count batch's result is **NOT** printed to $SPARK_HOME/work/../..stdout in each worker node.

Here is my each spark worker node's settings of resource in  $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh:

```
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=master
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=4
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=3g
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=2
```

I have 5 virtual machine nodes (in hostnames here): mykafka, master, data1, data2, and data3.

Thank you for any of your help and advice in advance.

The followings are the exceptions of **RpcTimeoutException** found in each worker:

> ```
> 16/04/11 23:07:30 WARN NettyRpcEndpointRef: Error sending message [message = Heartbeat(5,[Lscala.Tuple2;@2628a359,BlockManagerId(5, data3, 34838))] in 1 attempts
> org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply in 10 seconds. This timeout is controlled by spark.executor.heartbeatInterval
>   at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:48)
>   at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:63)
>   at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
>   at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
>   at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:185)
>   at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
>   at scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:185)
>   at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324)
>   ....
>   ....
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply in 10 seconds
>   at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anon$1.run(NettyRpcEnv.scala:242)
>   ... 7 more
> 16/04/11 23:07:31 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
> beat(5,[Lscala.Tuple2;@2628a359,BlockManagerId(5, data3, 34838))] in 1 attempts
> org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply in 10 seconds. This timeout is controlled by spark.executor.heartbeatInterval
>   at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:48)
>   at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:63)
>   at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
>   ....
>   ....
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply in 10 seconds
>   at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anon$1.run(NettyRpcEnv.scala:242)
>   ... 7 more
> ```

Comment: you said that you have  5 virtual machines are they able to connect to each other?  
Is there a firewall that is preventing them from accessing certain ports?
Are you Servers bound to a public interface?

Comment: Yes, they are able to connect to each other via SSH password less settings.  And I am able to submit  other spark jobs in yarn client mode successfully.  Also from the master node, I am able to connect to "mykafka" node.

Comment: I submitted it in yarn client mode, and found one of the executors cannot be launched:

{{JAVA_HOME}}/bin/java -server -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill %p' -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -Djava.io.tmpdir={{PWD}}/tmp '-Dspark.driver.port=44618' -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=<LOG_DIR> -XX:MaxPermSize=256m org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend --driver-url spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I had the exact same issue with this example and it seems to be related to this bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13906

Not sure how to set this for the example but I have been experimenting with the code, building a small scala app and had add a additional config parameter to the SparkConf()

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
.setAppName('name')
.set("spark.rpc.netty.dispatcher.numThreads","2")
```

Credit to David Gomez and the spark mailer where after alot of googleing I found the solution

https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201603.mbox/%3CCAAn_Wz1ik5YOYych92C85UNjKU28G+20s5y2AWgGrOBu-Uprdw@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: No problem I came across this post yesterday having the same problem just found the correct google phrase to find that mailer

Comment: Robrotheram,  thank you again.  Your help is very important to me.  It also benefits my other on going projects and plans too.  I was trying to tune all of different spark-submit parameters or configurations, but none of them works on the development cluster, and I am not able to see whether this gonna perform well from Streaming tab of Spark UI.  This information is helpful and really a big step to me.

Alan